# Child component not connecting to store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a component that connects to a store and displays a child component like below:

```js
 render() {
        return <div>
            <div className="userBox">
               <ProfilePhoto userid={this.props.id} />
            </div>
             <div className="nameTitleBox">
                <div className="firstLastTitle">
                    <h1>{this.props.firstName} {this.props.lastName}</h1>
                </div>
                <IDBox userid={this.props.id} />
            </div>
            <div className="childcomponent">
                <childComponent />
            </div>
             <div className="profileBox">
                <EditInterests interestsList={this.props.interest} />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

export default connect(
 (state) => state.user,
 UserState.actionCreators
)(User);
```

I want the child component to be a smart component that loads it's own data and controls everything itself. The code for it is pretty simple.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ApplicationState } from '../../store';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as ChildState from '../../store/childStore';

export class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props;
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
                        <div className="textCenter"><h2 id="sss">{this.props.text}</h2></div>
                        <div className="textRight">
                                <input type="button" className="button" value="Yes" /> <b className="textColor">No</b>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>)
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return { 
        action: dispatch(ChildState.actionCreators.requestChildren())
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapDispatchToProps,
    ChildState.actionCreators
)(ChildComponent);
```

this.props in the child component is always an empty object. Nothing from the child state is in there, the initial state, the actions, dispatch...anything. I've tried a few different things. ChildState loads fine if I actually load it in the parent. Don't know why it's not loading in the child and connecting the props.

Adding the store below:

```js
import { Action, Reducer } from 'redux';
import { fetch, addTask } from 'domain-task';
import { AppThunkAction } from './';

export const actionCreators = {
    requestChildren: () => (dispatch, getState) => {
        let url = 'random';
        var myheaders = new Headers();
        myheaders.append("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        let fetchTask = fetch(url, {
                headers: myheaders,
                credentials: "same-origin"
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                dispatch({ type: 'POST_ACTION', children: data });
            });
        addTask(fetchTask);
    }
}

export const initialState = { ... };

export const reducer = (state = initialState, incomingAction) => {
    const action = incomingAction;
    switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUEST_ACTION':
        return {
          ...
        };
    case 'POST_ACTION':
        return {
        ...
        };
    default:
    }

    return state || initialState;
};
```

Comment: In the child component's `connect` function, `mapDispatchToProps` should be the second argument instead of first.

Comment: That was actually from me just trying different things seeing if was doing things wrong. I switched it and still no dispatch or events in props.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is in mapDispatchtoProps have you tried using [bindActionCreators](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/bindActionCreators.html)

bindActionCreators make sure action (ChildState.actionCreators.requestChildren) flows through the middleware if there is any and then to the reducers

```
import { bindActionCreators} from 'redux';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        ChildState.actionCreators.requestChildren}, dispatch); }

export default connect(
    ChildState.actionCreators,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ChildComponent);
```

Comment: Attempted adding the bindActionCreators. Still getting empty props. I had to tweak some things to get it to bundle properly but I think it's the same idea?

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        requestChild: () => {
            dispatch(ChildState.actionCreators.requestChildren());
        }
    });
}

Answer (score 1):

This was happening because I was exporting both the child component and the connect function. I removed the export on the child component and its working now as expected.